# Express 1.2738068e-53 in percentage

Tags: probability

from the following equation I got these values (odds ratios) but now I need to express them in % thanks heaps in advance!

SUCCESS=  1/(1+EXP [ -(-121.952+8.053 GPA+0.157 GMAT)])

Therefore, the odds ratio of GPA is 
e^(-121.952+8.053)=3.4221009e-50
And the odds ratio for GMAT is 
e^(-121.952+0.157)=1.2738068e-53

Comment: $0.\underbrace{00\cdots00}_{50\text{ zeroes}}12738068\,\%$ ?

Comment: I am a physicist at heart, so... 0% :-)

Comment: Thanks heaps @HenningMakholm!!

Comment: Agree @Martigan thanks for replying!

Comment: Note that I strongly doubt that this is the number you want. I can't know for sure since you're not describing what you're trying to do, but what you have looks like a formula where you're supposed to insert someone's GPA and GMAT scores to get how likely they are to succeed at something. You've computed something like the odds that someone with a GPA of 1.0 and a GMAT score of 0 succeeds, respectively someone with a clear 0.0 GPA and a GMAT score of 1 -- which isn't very realistic, particularly since the lowest _possible_ GMAT score is 200 ...

Comment: I see what you mean @HenningMakholm. These are expressing the meaning of the regression coefficients for a model involving GPA and GMAT as independent variables (SPSS) so according to these results, when the other variable is fixed, 1 unit increase in GPA will lead to 0% increase in probability of success...I tried it with other values and got 0.11 % that's why the e- put me off :) thanks again!

Comment: @Probabilities: No, that's not right. A 1 unit increase in GPA will lead to a 8.053 increase in the [logit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) of the success probability -- but how much of a _percentage_ that is depends on the starting point. If the starting probability was very low, the success probability will _increase_ by a factor of $e^{8.053}\approx 3143$. On the other hand if the starting probability was close to 1, the probability of _failure_ will _decrease_ by a factor of 3143.

Comment: Note that $\alpha\to\frac1{1+e^{-\alpha}}$ is the inverse logit function, which is a commonly used technique to rescale the interval $(0,1)$ of possible probabilities to cover the entire real axis such that (for example) linear regressions won't lead to probabilities less than 0 or greater than 1. The value of $e^{-\alpha}$ doesn't make as much sense on its own as either $\alpha$ or the probability does.

Comment: Since the GMAT factor of $0.157$ is closer to $0$, we can use the approximation $e^x\approx x+1$ and say that a 1-point increase in GMAT score will lead to something between increasing the success probability by a factor of $1.16$ and decreasing the failure probability by a similar factor.